# Apache mod_rewrite with '/' in url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We have this rule in the config:

```
RewriteRule (\w+)\/place_info\/(\d+)(\/.+|\/?)$ $1/place_info.php?id=$2 [QSA]
```

Which is used to take URL's of the form

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/section/place_info/12345/place-name-whatever
```

and internally pass it as

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/section/place_info.php?id=12345
```

This works just fine in all cases except when the `place-name-whatever` has a URL-encoded `/` character in it.  For example, this works:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/section/place_info/12345/place-name-whatever
```

and this works:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/section/place_info/12345/place-name-whatever/with-slash
```

however this doesn't:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/section/place_info/12345/place-name-whatever%2Fwith-slash
```

For the hell of me I can't figure out what's happening here, and, more importantly, how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to [mod_rewrite bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34602) which is still unresolved for a pretty long time.

It affects you if you even discard the remaining line.

Comment: Yep, looks like this bug.  Awful!